# How do you estimate a forecast interval for a conditional forecast?

Tags: regression, forecasting

I know the interval for a unconditional forecast. However, my question is:

How do you estimate a forecast interval for a conditional forecast?

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Can you give us a hint of the context of your question? Are you talking about regression, time series, etc. ?

Comment: @soakley The question came to me when I read about conditional forecasting in my uni script.(its mostly about time series in this case, but also about regression)

Comment: More information please. Almost every forecast is conditional on something.